# How to download a specific part of any online streaming videos on Android phone?

Tags: downloading

I'm using an Android phone. I watch action movies online in it. I always want to download only some particular scenes of the movie. But I don't know how. So I download the complete movies which are very large in size and I cut specific parts of it using softwares. But I want to download only some parts of the online videos which are very small in size as compared to the whole movie. So my question is, is there any way to download parts of online streaming videos on Android. I'm not talking about YouTube videos. I'm taking about videos from movie websites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different Screen recorders for your requirement. Just start the recording where you wish to, and stop it when your are done. This way you can get your required length of video.

I'll try to list my top picks for the same.

1. **AZ Screen Recorder**: AZ Screen Recorder is the gold standard for screen recorder apps. It's light, easy, accessible, and cheap. It doesn't require root, has no watermarks and no time limits.
2. **DU Recorder** : It records your phone screen with up to 1080p/60fps quality. The app also works in 20 languages, has a decent UI, and a video editor built-in. It's all entirely free to download and use. It does have problems, though. Tablet support is a bit flaky and some people found bugs. Still, for free price, it's one of the better screen recording apps.
3. **Vysor**: Vysor is a fun little app that allows you to cast your device to your computer screen over USB. From there, you can use it on your computer or screen record it on your PC if you’d like to. It tends to work pretty well although you will need to fork out a little bit of money in order to get HD quality. This app doesn’t record anything on its own so don’t expect any options to do so. You’ll have to record it on your computer on your own.

   Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to help.please accept the answer if it satisfied your query